# How do I do a Barrel Roll?

Tags: starfox-64

Ok, so I'm playing Starfox 64, and this so-called "Peppy" hare keeps yelling at me:

> Do a barrel roll!

What's his problem? And what is this barrel roll he's talking about?

Comment: This question made my day.

Comment: I'm not clear on something.  Is this taking place _before_ or _after_ the hatches are open?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you look at the screen, you will notice it'll give you a hint on how to perform the barrel roll in the text blurb.

You can perform a barrel roll by pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> twice

Here is a video showing the blurb and a successful barrel roll.

Comment: Of course it's really an [aileron roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aileron_roll). ;) (vs. [barrel roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_roll))

Answer (score 13):

If I recall correctly, double tap the R or Z keys on top of the controller. Its when your craft spins left or right. Great for avoiding incoming enemy's or projectiles.

Comment: L is not easily accessible the way the N-64 controller is usually held. I believe Z is the other control usual listed for barrel roles. Does L also work?

Comment: "Press Z or R twice!" -- the man himself, Peppy Hare.

Answer (score 10):

(Z or R twice)!!